# How to change the tittle of DrawerLayout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I want to change the tittle of `DrawerLayout` from different Fragment.See the senario is that i have a navigation drawer in my app as well as on the home page i have a `GridView` from which the user can also navigate through the application .So the tittle is getting set properly on click of navigation but on click of the `gridview` item it is not getting changed how can we do this .

In **Fragment Activity**

```
public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
```

But how can we set this from the Fragment Class that is Dashboard and the DrawerLayout is in the FragmentActivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call **changeTitle();** method of your MainFragment be following code:

```
    if(getActivity() instanceof MainFragment){
((MainFragment)getActivity()).changeTitle("new Title")
}
```

And create changeTitle(String) mehtod in MainFragment:

```
   public void changeTitle(String newTitle){
getActionBar().setTitle(newTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); 
}
```

That is it.

Comment: so how it will change the Tittle of the DrawerLayout

Comment: i am getting this error when i am calling from Fraegment class to Main Activity 

Incompatible conditional operand types FragmentActivity and MainActivity

Comment: which is your main activity? name of main acitvity?

Comment: MainFragment is the main activity